# how to print a message in rails json format

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3

From my controller I am returning with

```
respond_with(@employee)
```

And in the json.erb file I am printing it as

```
{
            "EmpID": "<%=@employee.id%>",
            "details": "<%=@employee.body%>"

}
```

And IN the RestClient tool I am getting the output as below

```
{
   "EmpID": "E100925",
   "details": "{"Empcode"=>"E001", "date"=>"01-12-2013", "name"=>"David", "position"=>"12", "place"=>"UK"}"
}
```

I would like to put the meaningful message above (as "The employee details of XYZ company are")and then print the json hash. How to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean you want to just display your message? If so, simply type your message in your json file. Eg:

`The employee details of <%=@company.name%> company are
 {
  "EmpID": "<%=@employee.id%>",
  "details": "<%=@employee.body%>"
 }`

Comment: in the json.erb file..? I tried to do it... But it was not displaying anything

Comment: what I have is a json.erb file.So I am testing an api in restclient tool

Comment: I tried it in my app/views/example/exmpl.json file and it is working

Comment: In the browser it displays fine..But I am checking in the Firefox RESTClient tool. So there I see it as blank.

Comment: The problem is since my <%=@employee.body%> is a string with hash, in browser it displays with "details" : "{&quot;id&quot;=&gt;&quot;31&quot;, &quot;date&quot;=&gt;&quot;01-12-2013&quot; etc

Answer (score 0):

Json has its own fromat, And it always been several pairs of "key" and "value". If you want have some thing like that, maybe you can try to use *.html.erb.